# Request Url ToString overlapping Id's

Tags: c#, if-statement

I ran into a little problem. I am working on a line of If statement for a C# site,

`if(Request.Url.ToString().Contains("domain/Details/92")) { <img src="some-image.jpg" class="if-image"> }`

The problem I am having is the fact that my Id's are overlapping, so the if statement calls the image from "domain/details/2" into the "domain/details/92".

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: If its always on domain/Details/XX, why not extract the url segment containing the ID and match on the number directly via a switch statement?

Comment: Thank you for your idea, could you give me an example ? :)

Comment: Is this really what you want to do? You've just passed through a whole bunch of routing and (possibly, if you're using MVC) a controller where you can set up model variables to indicate to your view what needs to be done. Doing this in the view seems like a mixing of concerns to me.

Comment: so far thats the best idea i came up with, since im not that familiar with c# and im trying to help out a buddy of mine to revamp his site from 2010

Comment: What do you mean with ID's overlapping? Aren't the id's unique? If you are using c# you can set id's in hidden fields if you use aspx. With MVC you can use models and viewbags to pass id's.